# Get relative path from jar file

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I tried to reach a special path in Ubuntu, relative to the current jar file.
In Windows it is working without any problem:

```
String jarPath = Configuration.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
File f = new File(jarPath+"/../../configurationFile.xml");
```

However, in Linux I always get the jar file but I cannot step back two directories to the configurationFile.xml

```
/some/directory/where/xml/is/located/xyz.jar/configurationFile.xml: Not a directory
```

However, if I do

```
pwd /some/directory/where/xml/is/located/xyz.jar/../../
```

it works without any problems.

What I am doing wrong here?

I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Try using File.separator instead slashes: `new File(File.separator + "home" + File.separator + "somewhere");`

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only directories in your path.
After you determined the path to your jar file, extract the path to its directory and use directories only.

Comment: Hi, this worked great. I splitted the path and reconnected it the way I needed it, now it works! Thank you very much.